# CSV Columns removed From file while loading Dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

While loading csv via databricks, below the 2nd row 4th column is not loaded.
The csv's no of columns varies per row.

In test_01.csv,

```
a,b,c
s,d,a,d
f,s
```

Loaded above csv file via databricks as below

```
>>> df2 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").load("sample_files/test_01.csv")
>>> df2.show()
+---+---+----+
| C0| C1|  C2|
+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|   c|
|  s|  d|   a|
|  f|  s|null|
+---+---+----+
```

1. Tried loading with textfile

> > > rdd = sc.textFile ("sample_files/test_01.csv")
> > >
> > > rdd.collect()

```
[u'a,b,c', u's,d,a,d', u'f,s']
```

But not conversion of above rdd to dataframe causes error

2. Was able to solve by specifying the schema as below.

> > > df2 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(schema).load("sample_files/test_01.csv")
> > >
> > > df2.show()

```
+---+---+----+----+----+
| e1| e2|  e3|  e4|  e5|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|  a|  b|   c|null|null|
|  s|  d|   a|   d|null|
|  f|  s|null|null|null|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

3. Tried with inferschema. still not working

> > > df2 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load("sample_files/test_01.csv")
> > >
> > > df2.show()

```
+---+---+----+
| C0| C1|  C2|
+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|   c|
|  s|  d|   a|
|  f|  s|null|
+---+---+----+
```

But is there any other way without using schema as the no of column varies?

Comment: can you try `.option("inferSchema", "true")` i.e. `sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true").load("sample_files/test_01.csv")`

Comment: already tried that.. not working..

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have fixed headers ie rows can have a data missing but column names should  be fixed.

If you don't specify column names, you can still create the schema while reading the csv:

```
val schema = new StructType()
    .add(StructField("keyname", StringType, true))
```